# org-mode and file column indicator (fci-mode)

Tags: org-mode, fill-column

When using the fill-column-indicator package with org mode, I get wrong argument errors when exiting the source block editing window, issues with utf-8 character artefacts in source blocks exported to html and some other minor quirks. How can you fix this?

Current emacs 25.1 and org-mode 9.0.5

Comment: fci-mode is a nightmare.  It causes issues with way too many other modes.  I would recommend just using whitespace-mode instead.  I've never had any problems with it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with org-mode and fci-mode. See [here](https://github.com/alpaker/Fill-Column-Indicator/issues/45) and [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg90441.html) for a discussion and some suggested solutions. Personally, I found the cure to be worse than the symptom and it didn't quite fit with what I wanted.

I have instead found an alternative which works with org-mode and still provides me with the sort of information I was after with fci-mode. I found it was trivial to get similar functionality with whitespace-mode. Rather than a vertical line indicating the fill column, a face is used to colour all characters past the fill line with a different colour.

```
  (use-package whitespace-cleanup-mode
    :ensure t
    :diminish whitespace-cleanup-mode
    :init
    (setq whitespace-cleanup-mode-only-if-initially-clean nil
          whitespace-line-column 80
          whitespace-style '(face lines-tail))
    :config
    (global-whitespace-mode)
    (global-whitespace-cleanup-mode))
```